# Why is "event" accessible in Vue v-on methods even without the argument?

Tags: vue.js

According to the page on event handling in the docs for Vue, when you use v-on like `v-on:click="handler"` the handler function will automatically get the original DOM event as the first argument. This code snippet is directly adapted from those docs.

```js
new Vue({
  // Vue config shortened for brevity
  methods: {
    handler(event) {
      // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
      alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
      // `event` is the native DOM event
      if (event) {
        alert(event.target.tagName)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Why the heck can I still access `event` even if I omit it from the functions parameter list like this:

```js
handler() {
  console.log(event); // Still returns the native DOM object even though
                      // I don't explicitly define `event` anywhere
}
```

Shouldn't `event` be `undefined` if I don't add it as an argument to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that'll be the global `window.event`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Nothing to do with Vue, it's just an unfortunate coincidence that you happened to call it `event`.

Comment: When I triggered the debugger in Chrome, I couldn't find a global variable called `event`. Does it not normally show up?

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin start typing *"eve..."* in Chrome's console. You'll see the autocomplete *"event"*, as well as *"Event"*, which is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). The first one is the global (window) described in this answer.

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin Scroll down to near the bottom of **Global**. You'll find it lurking just after `eval` in the greyed-out section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the docs explains the reason to use `event` in the handler function as first argument:
`You should avoid using this property in new code, and should instead use the Event passed into the event handler function.`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event